# Managing between local-Storage and back-end Database storage on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am making an iPad application.

Where I fill some form and submit the save the form data.
Now here is the catch:-

1. If the the iPad has internet connectivity, data should be sent to back-end database via an API call.
2. Otherwise It should be saved in the local storage without the user knowing anything.
3. There is a screen where User sees previously filled forms list, [lats one week or so] which he can edit. Not knowing whether it has synced or not.

Data is synced with back-end when the user comes online and hits a sync button.

I am using Core Data for local Storage and there is a MySQL back-end with a RoR WS API in front.

Now I have multiple questions regarding the implementation of the entity schema design and and caching technique.

I don't want to make things overly complicated.

All suggestions are welcome :)

**My Questions**

- The unique id for each form data is auto-generated at the back-end . So when I have data saved locally and not synced with the back-end, what id , it should be having ?
- How long should I keep data in the local storage and when should I delete relatively old data.
- Important factor is, user will not always have connectivity, his login state will also be cached into user-defaults.